# Is every number in the code considered a "magic number"?

Tags: programming-practices

So every number in the code that we are sending to a method as an argument is considered as a Magic Number? 
To me, it shouldn't.  I think if some number is let's say it is for minimum length of user name and we start using "6" in the code...then yeah we have a maintenance problem and here "6" is a magic number....but if we are calling a method that one of its arguments accept an integer for example as the ith member of a collection and then we pass "0" to that method call, in this case I don't see that "0" as a magic number. 
What do you think?

Comment: In your example, what does the 0 represent?

Comment: In the case you illustrate, that "0" has no magical properties whatsoever.

Comment: Everything except 0,1 and 42 is magic

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If the meaning of the number is *very* clear in the context, I don't think it's a "magic number" problem.

Example: Let's say you're trying to get the substring of a string, from the beginning to some token and the code looks like this (imaginary language and library):

```
s := substring(big_string, 0, findFirstOccurence(SOME_TOKEN, big_string));
```

In this context, the meaning of the number 0 is clear enough. I suppose you could define `START_OF_SUBSTRING` and set it to 0, but in this case I think it would be overkill (although it would be the correct approach if you knew that the start of your substring might not be 0, but that depends on the specifics of your situation).

Another example might be if you are trying to determine if a number is even or odd. Writing:

```
isEven := x % 2;
```

is not as strange as:

```
TWO := 2;
isEven := x % TWO;
```

Testing negative numbers as

```
MINUS_ONE := -1;
isNegativeInt := i <= MINUS_ONE;
```

also feels weird to me, I'd much rather see

```
isNegativeInt := i <= -1;
```

Comment: To throw another example on there, in code where you're explicitly working with degrees on a circle, it would be fair to use a number such as `360` to mark a full rotation with the understanding that most people will know what that means (though this is a case where it wouldn't *hurt* to provide a constant)

Comment: KChaloux: If I could, I would -1 your comment. 360 is a magic number. If 360 happens to be a value for another constant, then you have 2 sets for 360 that are unrelated and indistinguishable. Junior comes along, go "That is a magic number", global search and replace 360 with "Degrees_in_Circle", run all unit and regression tests, all pass - delivers code fix. Code now a dogs breakfast, and we all know what happens to that after a short time.......

Comment: @mattnz: Hopefully that kind of large-scale code change would be quickly caught (hopefully during code review, if they're that junior) long before it ever got into production. I think someone who would do that in that context would probably also replace `0` in the context of the my substring example. In which case, this might be the *least* amount of damage they can cause. It's been a long time since I did any coding that did geometric calculations, but generally, the values 15, 30, 45, 60, 90, 180, 360 were constants that were accepted. I've never seen anyone define `FIFTEEN_DEGREES`,...

Comment: @KChaloux The example may actually fall apart if there's a shift from Degrees to Radians.  By 360, you are expressing 1 complete rotation.  Since there are multiple representations for the same value, it should be pulled out.  Especially considering 360PI could look the same as 2PI (180 rotations but still pointing the same direction in the end), or 360 rotations the same as 1 rotation, but side effects may be different.

Comment: @KChaloux: Also, by you reasoning, 3.1415926 is not a magic number, neither is 6.626068 × 10^-34, or 299792458 or 9.81 or  4.47*10^9. Surely PI, PLANKS_CONSTANT, SPEED_OF_LIGHT, GRAVITY_ACCELERATION, URANIUM_HALFLIFE make easier to read and maintain code and are as likely to be changed as 360 degrees in a circle.

Comment: A bit of a straw man there, TWO and MINUS_ONE are utterly bad because replacing a magic number with its rendering in text is OF COURSE idiotic. The name of the constant has to convey its meaning. Except your examples are about fundamental facts about numbers, closely tied to just those specific numbers, so there isn't really any meaning beyond that.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I wish all languages had the imaginary operator ":=" instead of "=" :D

Comment: @Songo: FWIW, Oracle PL/SQL uses `:=` instead of `=` for assignment. There are others too, I just don't recall which ones.

Comment: TWO -> SMALLEST_EVEN_NUMBER; MINUS_ONE -> SMALLEST_NEGATIVE_INTEGER. Still overkill, but then at least the names would make sense. In that last case you should always check < 0 rather than <= -1, though.

Comment: There seems to be a split understanding of magic numbers going on here (mostly in these comments). Magic numbers are purely about code clarity (that's why we call unclear numbers "magic"), constants are not the only way to make the intentions of a number clear. Magic numbers have nothing to do with DRYing up numeric literals, though the concepts often overlap.

DRYing up numeric literals is a good but separate practice, that comes with all the same pitfalls of DRY code. (make your code dry, but don't over-do it)

Comment: I've done more research and have seen people use both definitions of the phrase "magic number". It's unfair for me to say that one side is correct and the other isn't. It's good to realize that our community has two separate but similar definitions for magic number: "unclear number" or "non-DRY number". This means the answers to this question will all be influenced by an opinion by which definition the answerer is using.

Answer (score 19):

```
bool hasApples = apples > 0;
```

It is obvious zero means absence. I find 0 easier to understand than a variable named "absenceValue".

```
for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

It's obvious 0 is the starting position. I would be confused by a variable named "firstPosition". Such a variable would make me wonder if the starting position could change.

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest three key factors in deciding whether something should be a constant declaration:

1. Is the number something that is precisely and concisely representable

   Are there any plausible scenarios under which the value would have to change, but the code would not have to be rewritten

   Would someone who sees the number be apt to recognize it more quickly or less quickly than someone who sees a named constant

Something like pi should probably be written as a named constant, rather than as a numeric literal, since a numeric literal is apt to be needlessly verbose, needlessly imprecise, or both.  Something like the number of slots in a cache should likely be a named constant (though see note below) to allow for the possibility of expanding the cache without having to modify all the code that uses it.  Things like the numbers "4", "28", and "29" in the statement `if ((year % 4)==0) FebruaryDays = 29; else FebruaryDays = 28;` should probably not be named constants, since the expression is almost certainly more readable than `if ((year % YearsBetweenLeapYears)==0) FebruaryDays = FebruaryDaysInLeapYear; else FebruaryDays = FebruaryDaysInNonLeapYear;`.  Note that the maintainers of standards have indicated that the length of February 2100 in that year will not match the above formula, but I would recommend *not* handling that case unless it would be the *only* impediment to correctly handling such dates (i.e. the code won't get tripped by integer overflow or other such problems).

An important caveat with rule #2 is that in some cases code may rely upon hard-coded numbers in a way which cannot readily be represented by a named constant.  For example, a method which computes a cross product of two vectors passed as discrete parameters will only be meaningful when used on three-dimensional vectors.  The required number of dimensions is not a value that could meaningfully be changed without completely rewriting the routine.  Even if one foresaw a possible need for computing the cross product of three 4-dimensional vectors, using a named constant for the value "3" would do little to make it easier to satisfy that need.

Comment: I call people not handling leap years correctly for all years “halfwits”. People who do it intentionally - I have no name for that. Saboteur maybe?

Comment: @gnasher729: Most real-time clock chips have a decimal year counter that only goes from 00 to 99, and will advance from `00-02-28 23:59:59` to `00-02-29 00:00:00`, and the same continues to be true of many real-time clock modules that are being incorporated into new designs.  The only way dates will possibly be able to work correctly in 2100 will be if either (1) a system is modified to use a different clock chip, which would likely require reworking the system's time/date logic; (2) the system is modified so that after 2100-02-28 it expects all RTC dates to be off by one, ...

Comment: ...which would require reworking the time/date logic, or (3) governments decide to make 2100 be a leap year.  I suppose that having a separate function to handle conversion between linear time and RTC date-time, versus conversion between linear time and human-readable time might be better than using one function for both purposes, but my point is that any of three incompatible approaches may end up being needed to fix the problem, and I have no way of knowing which one would actually end up being correct.

Comment: @gnasher729: If I were to change a program today so that the date would default to 21-01-01, and years from 00 to 20 would be interpreted as 2100-2120, that would at best increase by about 20% the number of years the software could run without needing a change to its date-handling logic, but if on the first reboot after the upgrade the year read 20 or less the system would have to determine whether the system had previously been using old software (in which case the date should probably be set to a default 21-01-01) or new software (meaning the date should be interpreted as 2100+).

Answer (score 5):

This, as all principles, is a matter of degree. Generally speaking, number literals in source code are more suspect the larger they are. A maximum length like 10 or a memory address like 0x587FB0 are obviously bad practice - it is almost certain that sooner or later you will have to repeat these values more than once, creating a risk of incompatibility and subtle errors introduced in places that weren't changed.

0 is at the other end of the scale; it is still suspect but not quite as much. 
Are you using 0 as a sentinel value? Then you should probably use a symbolic constant instead, just because the constant can *explain* what it means. Is it an extremely entrenched cultural agreement such as "0 means successful completion"? That's probably OK. Does it mean "the first item in a collection"? That may be harmless, but if there is an alternate method such as `first()` I'd probably prefer that.

Comment: "Are you using 0 as a sentinel value?" <-- Can you explain what you mean by "sentinel" here?  I can't find a definition that seems to match.

Comment: @rory.ap "Sentinel" in this context means "a thing in its own right", independent of the numeric value "0".  COBOL programmers often used the character literal "1", assembler programmers frequently used 0xff, C programmers often followed the Standard Library string model of 0, _etc_.

Answer (score 5):

Every unnamed number that's not immediately obvious from context is a magic number.  Its a little silly to define numbers that have meaning that is immediately obvious from context.

In django (python web framework), I may define some database field with a raw number like:

```
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
middlename = models.CharField(max_length=40)
lastname =  models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

which is clearer (and the [recommended practice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/) ) than say

```
MAX_LENGTH_NAME = 40
...
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_LENGTH_NAME)
middlename = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_LENGTH_NAME)
lastname =  models.CharField(max_length=MAX_LENGTH_NAME)
```

as I'm unlikely to ever need to change the length (and can always compare to the `max_length` of the field).  If I do need to change the length of the field after initially deploying the application, I need to change it in exactly one location per field in my django code, and then additionally write a migration to change the schema of the DB.  If I ever need to reference `max_length` of a defined field of a type of object, I can do it directly -- if those fields were defining a `Person` class, I can use `Person._meta.get_field('firstname').max_length` to obtain the `max_length` being used (which is defined in one place).  The fact that the same 40 was used for multiple fields is irrelevant as I may want to change them independently.  The length of firstname should never depend on the length of middlename or lastname; they are separate values and can change independently.

Often array indices can use unnamed numbers; like if I have a CSV file of data that I want to put in a python dictionary, with the first element in the row as the dictionary `key` I would write:

```
mydict = {}
for row in csv.reader(f):
    mydict[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Sure I could name `index_column = 0` and do something like:

```
index_col = 0
mydict = {}
for row in csv.reader(f):
    mydict[row[index_col]] = row[:index_col] + row[index_col+1:]
```

or worse define `after_index_col = index_col + 1` to get rid of the `index_col+1`, but that doesn't make the code clearer in my view.  Also, if I give the `index_col` a name, I better make the code work even if the column is not 0 (hence the `row[:index_col] +` part).

Comment: Actually, `max_lngth=40` vs. `max_length=MAX_LENGTH_NAME` is a *classic* examlple of a magic number that *screams* to be a symbol.  The day will come when you want to support 45 character names, and now every use of "40" is suspect and must be carefully examined.

Comment: @RossPatterson - This is not C where we constantly compare against a global var MAX_ARRAY_SIZE, but a decent web framework.  The only place that the magic number comes up is where you declare the database model; everything else is compared against this value (e.g., 40 appears nowhere else in the code).  Also note, you can't change this variable easily without doing schema migrations as its tied to a DB.  If I wanted to change to say 1 character middle names its immediately obvious the one place to change in the code `40` to `1`.  You have to think of context.

Comment: Sorry, you're wrong on two points.  First, the OP asked a "programming practices" question that doesn't specify any language.  They said "method", not "function", so let's presume something object-oriented, but that doesn't take us out of the realm of magic-numbered data.  Second, if the magic number is baked into the database (*e.g.*, the schema), then it's even worse to have it in code.  The right thing to do is to get the magic almost-a-constant from its source - either the database itself or a schema module that centralizes all those constants-that-will-vary-over-the-code's-lifetime.

Comment: To reiterate the point that it depends on context: It's clear what 40 means here `models.CharField(max_length=40)`, but, if we chose to call it as `models.CharField(40)`, then 40 has become a magic number. We often think of constants as the solution to fix magic numbers, but this clearly shows that there are other ways.

Comment: @RossPatterson, the main reason we avoid magic numbers is to make code more legible (That's why we call them "magic" - we don't know what they do in their context). Turning 40 into a constant purely to DRY up the literal is a different, but often overlapping concept, and comes with all of the benefits and pitfalls of DRY code.

Comment: @ScottyJamison As a programmer with many decades of history, I've spent a fair portion of my life finding numeric constants, reverse-engineering their meaning, sqaushing variant values, and unifying those that had multiple definitions, often because the "constant" needed to change.  I made a lot of money doing exactly that as Y2K approached.  It's a perfectly valid reason for avoiding magic numbers, regardless if it meets your personal definition.

Comment: @RossPatterson I've done some more research, and have found entire articles talking about magic numbers the way I've defined them, and different articles talking about them the way you've defined them. Apparently we have one phrase in the community to portray two separate but similar ideas - that never ends well. This means 40 in `max_length=40` is magical depending on who we're talking too, and it's unfair to say half of the community is wrong because our co-workers use a certain definition (so sorry for calling you wrong).

Comment: Ross, it’s not just 40 that’s suspect. It’s also 39 which should be max_length - 1, or 80 which should be max_length * 2. And 79. And 120 (maximum number of UTF-8 bytes for 40 UTF-16 code points.

Comment: @gnasher729 did you read the answer? "If I ever need to reference max_length of a defined field of a type of object, I can do it directly -- if those fields were defining a Person class, I can use Person._meta.get_field('firstname').max_length to obtain the max_length being used"

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes numbers in code will never be changed.  With integer values, using symbolic names would obscure the code. For example:

```
   radians= (degrees * M_PI) / 180;
```

and

```
   degrees_fahrenheit= 32 + (degrees_celsius * 9) / 5;
```

Having code reflect the conversion equation maximizes readability.

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading the answers raising my eyebrows. I think all of them, including the Wikipedia page, are wrong.

To me a magic number is something very specific that has nothing to do with whether a constant has been defined for it or not. And I did not make this up myself.

A magic number is the computer science equivalent of in-band signaling. It means there is a number in a domain (say, integers) that gets assigned (semantically) a different meaning than its value. This is always problematic and often a hack to overcome some shortcoming in the programming language, it is an optimization or it's just a lazy shortcut.

Example: You have a variable Age and you want to abuse it to tell whether the person is still alive or not. This is where you go wrong already but you may be living in the 1960s and be short on memory. You come up with the idea of using 200 to signal someone is dead. That would make 200 a magic number.

In this case it may be obvious there is something about 200 because nobody makes 200 but the potential problems are obvious. You have to be aware of this hack every time you do something with ages. You can no longer just calculate an average age without being aware of it for example.

The classic example of this being a problem is an old AT&T phone system that used a particular frequency not often used in speech to terminate the call. This did not work out well, people whistling over the phone was enough to drop the call.

Comment: "I've been reading the answers raising my eyebrows. I think all of them, including the Wikipedia page, are wrong." That's a very strong claim, you should definitely back up your claims with references which could support them.

Comment: @VincentSavard  My understanding of the term and the anecdote come from one of Andrew Tanenbaum's books, probably Computer Networks. I did some searches.and found a wikipedia page that links magic numbers to in-band signaling: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-band_signaling  This does however only name file identifiers as an example,, not their usage in code.

Answer (score 0):

As in everything, context is everything.  A couple of simple rules of thumb should be kept in mind: 1) the more frequently it is used, the more likely it is to deserve a name, 2) if the reason why it is that number instead of another number isn’t clear without knowing more than is in the function/method, it deserves a name to explain it.

0 seldom needs a name, because it’s generally clear from context, but there can certainly be circumstances where it’s unclear, where a name or a comment is necessary to explain why it was used. Determining even/odd with a modulo 2 is clear, giving a 50% discount might not be clear whether it is done with a multiplication or a division.  Context is everything.

In your specific example, zero would represent the first element of the collection, but you might want to have a name that explains why the first and not the last…