# Are magic numbers acceptable in unit tests if the numbers don't mean anything?

Tags: unit-testing

In my unit tests, I often throw arbitrary values at my code to see what it does.  For example, if I know that `foo(1, 2, 3)` is supposed to return 17, I might write this:

```
assertEqual(foo(1, 2, 3), 17)
```

These numbers are purely arbitrary and have no broader meaning (they are not, for example, boundary conditions, though I do test on those as well).  I would struggle to come up with good names for these numbers, and writing something like `const int TWO = 2;` is obviously unhelpful.  Is it OK to write the tests like this, or **should I factor the numbers out into constants?**

In [Are all magic numbers created the same?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/266717/are-all-magic-numbers-created-the-same), we learned that magic numbers are OK if the meaning is obvious from context, but in this case the numbers actually have no meaning at all.

Comment: If you're putting values in and expecting to be able to read those same values back, I'd say magic numbers are fine. So if, say, `1, 2, 3` are 3D array indices where you previously stored the value `17`, then I think this test would be dandy (as long as you have some negative tests as well). But if it's the result of a calculation, you should make sure that anyone reading this test will understand why `foo(1, 2, 3)` should be `17`, and magic numbers probably won't achieve that goal.

Comment: [Related](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/299372/does-context-like-as-an-argument-in-a-function-allow-for-numbers-in-code-that/299375#299375)

Comment: `const int TWO = 2;` is even worse than just using `2`. It's conforming to wording of the rule with intent to violate it's spirit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is every number in the code considered a “magic number”?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/181921/is-every-number-in-the-code-considered-a-magic-number)

Comment: You know they're arbitrary, how does someone else know that?

Comment: What is a number that "doesn't mean anything"? Why would it be in your code if it meant nothing?

Comment: Sure.  Leave a comment before a series of such tests, e.g., "a small selection of manually determined examples".  This, in relation to your other tests which are clearly testing boundaries and exceptions, will be clear.

Comment: Your example is misleading - when your function name would be really `foo`, it would not mean anything, and so the parameters. But in reality, I am pretty sure the function does not have that name, and the parameters don't have names `bar1`, `bar2`, and `bar3`. Make a more realistic example where the names *have*  a meaning, then it makes much more sense to discuss if the test data values need a name, too.

Comment: @timster: Some functions can do several things, selected via one of the arguments.  Some of the other arguments may be used for some operations but not others.  If a function is supposed to ignore an argument in a certain situation, what value should be passed to ensure that it it is doing so?

Comment: This is a semi-related question on the CodeReview.SE site: ['100' is a magic number](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44047/34757)

Comment: @supercat, the answer to your question depends on the language. But, a concrete example would help.

Comment: @timster: Suppose a function includes two parameters "*dat" and "dat_length" and specifies that if `dat` is null, then `dat_length` will be ignored (and otherwise the function will e.g. read `dat_length` bytes from somewhere and store them at `*dat`).  If the function is supposed to ignore `dat_length` when `dat` is null, the call should be tested with a null `dat` and non-zero `dat_length`, but I don't think any particular non-zero value is apt to be more or less meaningful than any other.

Comment: they're not magic if they dont' mean anything. the magic in a magic number is the undocumented meaning.   The number 5 isn't a magic number.   But a 5 meaning something needs to be multiplied by 5 because it needs to be a multiple of 5 somewhere later down the line is a magic number.

Comment: @davidbak: nah, we all know that comments are admissions of failure and names should be used to self-document. So don't write a comment "a small selection of manually determined values", define an array `small_selection_of_manually_determined_values = [ [1, 2, 3, 17], ...]`. But then, maybe we should have a structure to represent each test case, with named fields. We're not leaving until this is at least 4 extra lines of code, 16 if coding style dictates use of getters :-)

Comment: @DocBrown OK.  For example the function is `volume(height, width, depth)`.  The unit test contains among others this assertion `assertEqual(volume(1, 2, 3), 17)`.  It should fail.  Upon investigation, the team should realize that there is an error in the assertion.  The choices of 1, 2, and 3 are still arbitrary and there is no logical reason to name them.

Comment: it's literally impossible they have "no meaning".  Assign them names, which, express their meaning. That's all that has to be said on the entire issue.

Comment: @emory: see my answer below.

Comment: We do something called "sanity checking" with exactly such values that would be valid and expected, as a first check. If passed, more thorough and formal testing (boundary conditions, complete coverage, etc.) is next.

Answer (score 81):

When do you really have numbers which have no meaning at all?

Usually, when the numbers have any meaning, you should assign them to local variables of the test method to make the code more readable and self-explaining. The names of the variables should at least reflect what the variable means, not necessarily its value.

Example:

```c
const int startBalance = 10000;
const float interestRate = 0.05f;
const int years = 5;

const int expectedEndBalance = 12840;

assertEqual(calculateCompoundInterest(startBalance, interestRate, years),
            expectedEndBalance);
```

Note that the first variable is not named `HUNDRED_DOLLARS_ZERO_CENT`, but `startBalance` to denote what's the meaning of the variable but not that its value is in any way special.

Comment: In my particular use case, I have a 3D array-like thing and I want to test that I can put data into it and pull the same data out again (because the internal implementation is complex enough that this could plausibly fail to work).  So under your proposal, I'd have names like `x`, `y`, `z`... but then what if I need more than one point to test slicing?  I'd really rather not create `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, etc.

Comment: @Kevin - what language are you testing in? Some testing frameworks let you set up data providers which return an array of arrays of values for testing

Comment: Though I agree with the idea, beware that this practice can introduce new errors too, like if you accidentally extract a value like `0.05f` to an `int`. :)

Comment: +1 - great stuff. Just because you don't care what a particular value is, that does not mean it isn't still a magic number...

Comment: I'm a bit confused about calling constants variables.

Comment: @PieterB: AFAIK that's the fault of C and C++, which formalised the notion of a `const` variable.

Comment: Have you named your variables the same as the named parameters of `calculateCompoundInterest`? If so, then the extra typing is a proof-of-work that you've read the documentation for the function you're testing, or at least copied the names given to you by your IDE. I'm not sure how much this tells the reader about the intent of the code, but if you pass the parameters in the wrong order at least they can tell what was intended.

Comment: @SteveJessop: At least they can vary from run to run ;p (or from call to call, or from loop iteration to loop iteration). Depends how we look at it philosophically: is a local `const int x` the same as "itself" during the next call? In any sense? Maybe. Sometimes not. It certainly may hold a different value. `const` implies post-initialisation immutability but I don't think that's entirely the same as a "constant" in the truest sense of the word.

Comment: You should mention, if these are local scoped variables in the method-body, or if you want to export them into constants in central place ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: if a local variable *is* the same as itself in the next call, then it's much harder to write re-entrant code. That's why the default in C is not to apply `static` to automatic variables. But sure, there's a difference between a const variable in a program, and a mathematical constant like π, even if a particular programming language encourages or forces you to use the former to represent the latter and thus you end up calling constants variables and confusing PieterB :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'm not talking about statics, or "variables" that retain their value across function calls. I'm talking about the philosophy of a bog standard local variable — is its existence defined by its name/identity or only its scope? ;p

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: then the answer is that "philosophically" it's a different object, and the C and C++ standards reify this clearly. If it were the same object in different calls to the function, then it couldn't have different values in re-entrant calls, because "the same object" cannot simultaneously have different values. It's only complicated because there are some contexts where we'll talk about "the integer in this function", or "the call to `foo()` in this function" even though of course we know it's a separate integer and a separate call each time through.

Comment: ... to be completely unambiguous we could say "the integer definition in this function", and "the callsite to `foo()` in this function", but nobody can be bothered.

Comment: @SteveJessop: My point was that the standard is not a philosophy and philosophically one could look at it either way. Especially when the whole topic is what "constant" means both extra- and intra-standard. But I think we've gone beyond this conversation being useful.....!

Comment: @JeffBowman Clearly we need tests for our tests.

Comment: Having just read all this, I wonder if there's a difference in terminology that people have been taught.  I've been taught that "const int x" means that x is a "constant", which the language often treats very similar to a variable, but it is not a variable (because it doesn't ever vary). Hence, PieterB's comment (like an instructor claiming "confusion" when a student claims something nonsense - he probably wasn't really confused) did well by pointing out the issue. @SteveJessop : I realize your comment is over a year old, but you said C "formalised" const variables... Is that cite-able?

Comment: @TOOGAM: not sure what you mean by cite-able. I don't know whether C was the *first* to do this or not, just that both standards formally state that there is such a thing as a `const` variable, so PieterB's confusion is built into the language.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using arbitrary numbers just to see what they do, then what you're really looking for is probably randomly generated test data, or property-based testing.

For example, [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a cool Python library for this sort of testing, and is based on [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck).

> Think of a normal unit test as being something like the following:
>
> 1. Set up some data.
> 2. Perform some operations on the data.
> 3. Assert something about the result.
>
> Hypothesis lets you write tests which instead look like this:
>
> 1. For all data matching some specification.
> 2. Perform some operations on the data.
> 3. Assert something about the result.

The idea is to not constrain yourself to your own values, but pick random ones that can be used to check that your function(s) match their specifications.  As an important note, these systems will generally remember any input that fails, and then ensure that those inputs are always tested in the future.

Point 3 can be confusing to some people so let's clarify. It doesn't mean that you're asserting the exact answer - this is obviously impossible to do for arbitrary input. Instead, you assert something about a **property** of the result. For example, you might assert that after appending something to a list it becomes non-empty, or that a self-balancing binary search tree is actually balanced (using whatever criteria that particular data structure has).

Overall, picking arbitrary numbers yourself is probably pretty bad - it doesn't really add a whole bunch of value, and is confusing to anyone else who reads it. Automagically generating a bunch of random test data and using that effectively is good. Finding a Hypothesis or QuickCheck-like library for your language of choice is probably a better way to accomplish your goals while remaining understandable to others.

Comment: Random testing may find bugs that are hard to reproduce but testing randomly hardly finds reproducible bugs. Be sure to capture any test failures with a specific reproducible test case.

Comment: NUnit has a similar function but it should be noted that unit tests should be *repeatable*. Very useful for other types of testing though...

Comment: In my experience, property-based testing is _very_ good at finding reproducible bugs. Good frameworks don't just throw random numbers at the tests, they let you specify the expected behaviour for different partitions of the domain, and zoom in on the location where the implementation and the specification diverge.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson I don't know about Hypothesis, but QuickCheck uses a reproducible and predictable sequence of test parameters to give consistency between test runs.

Comment: And how do you know that your unit test isn't bugged when you "assert something about the result" (in this case, recompute what `foo` is computing)...? If you were 100% sure your code gives the right answer, then you would just put that code in the program and not test it. If you're not, then you need to test the test, and I think everyone sees where this is going.

Comment: Yeah, if you pass random inputs into a function you have to know what the output would be to be able to assert that it is working correctly. With fixed/chosen test values you can of course work it out by hand, etc. but surely any automated method of detemining if the result is correct is subject to the exact same problems as the function you are testing. You either use the implementation you have (which you can't because you are testing whether it works) or you write a new implementation which is just as likely to be buggy (or moreso else you'd use the more likely to be correct one).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi - not necessarily. You could, for example, test that applying the inverse of the operation you're testing to the result gives back the initial value you started with.  Or you could test expected invariants (e.g. for all interest calculations at `d` days, the calculation at `d` days + 1 month should be a known monthly percentage rate higher), etc.

Comment: @Chris - In many cases, checking results are correct is easier than generating the results.  While this isn't true in *all* circumstances, there are lots where it is.  Example: adding an entry to a balanced binary tree should result in a new tree that is also balanced... easy to test, quite tricky to implement in practice.

Comment: @Jules: Ah yes. I was thinking in very basic terms of functions returning simple ints and stuff. I didn't really think about results where you could test properties on them without necessarily knowing the exact final state. Thanks for the response. :)

Comment: @JBRWilkinson The nice thing about Hypothesis is that when something fails it automatically remembers that test case and always tests against it in the future (it actually also does some magic to try and find the most general case that causes a failure).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Honestly I don't really know how Hypothesis/QuickCheck/etc actually work - just that they do. If you're curious or skeptical I encourage you to read more.

Comment: @Chris Property based testing is amazing and is actually easier to see with math-type functions using simple ints... For example, addition... does add(a,IDENTITY) = a? Does add(a,b) = add(b,a)? Does add(add(a,b),c) = add(a,add(b,c)) ? The only magic number in addition is the identity (for normal integer addition, IDENTITY = 0).

Answer (score 11):

Your unit test name should provide most of the context. Not from the values of the constants.  The name/documentation for a test should be giving the appropriate context and explanation of whatever magic numbers are present within the test.

If that is not sufficient, a slight bit of documentation should be able to provide it (whether through the variable name or a docstring). Keep in mind the function itself has parameters that hopefully have meaningful names. Copying those into your test to name the arguments is rather pointless.

And last, if your unittests are complicated enough that this is hard/not practical you probably have too complicated of functions and might consider why this is the case.

The more sloppily you write tests, the worse your actual code will be. If you feel the need to name your test values to make the test clear, it strongly suggests your actual method needs better naming and/or documentation. If you find the need to name constants in tests I would look into why you need this - likely the problem is not the test itself but implementation

Comment: This answer appears to be about the difficulty of inferring the purpose of a test whereas the actual question is about magic numbers in method parameters...

Comment: @RobbieDee the name/documentation for a test should be giving the appropriate context and explanation of whatever magic numbers are present within the test. If not, either add documentation or rename the test to be more clear.

Comment: It would still be better to give the magic numbers names. If the number of parameters were to change, the documentation risks becoming out of date.

Comment: @RobbieDee keep in mind the function itself has parameters that hopefully have meaningful names. Copying those into your test to name the arguments is rather pointless.

Comment: "Hopefully" huh? Why not just code the thing properly and do away with what is ostensibly a magic number as Philipp has already outlined...

Comment: @RobbieDee because the more sloppily you write the tests, the worse your actual code will be. If you feel the _need_ to name your test values to make it clear, it strongly suggests your actual method needs better naming and/or documentation. If you find the need to name constants in tests I would look into why you need this - likely the problem is not the test itself but implementation.

Comment: I'm not saying your suggestion doesn't have value, it just skirts round the main issue which is: Stop using magic numbers...

Comment: @RobbieDee I edited some to clarify... didn't realize that wasn't clear..

Answer (score 10):

This depends heavily on the function you are testing. I know lots of cases where the individual numbers do not have a special meaning on their own, but the test case as a whole is constructed thoughtfully and so has a specific meaning. That is what one should document in some way. For example, if `foo` really is a method `testForTriangle` which decides if the three numbers might be valid lengths of the edges of a triangle, your tests might look like this:

```
// standard triangle with area >0
assertEqual(testForTriangle(2, 3, 4), true);

// degenerated triangle, length of two edges match the length of the third
assertEqual(testForTriangle(1, 2, 3), true);  

// no triangle
assertEqual(testForTriangle(1, 2, 4), false); 

// two sides equal
assertEqual(testForTriangle(2, 2, 3), true);

// all three sides equal
assertEqual(testForTriangle(4, 4, 4), true);

// degenerated triangle / point
assertEqual(testForTriangle(0, 0, 0), true);
```

and so on. You might improve this and turn the comments into a message parameter of `assertEqual` which will be displayed when the test fails. You can then improve this further and refactor this into a data driven test (if your testing framework supports this). Nevertheless you do yourself a favor if you put a note into the code why you picked this numbers and which of the various behaviours you are testing with the individual case.

Of course, for other functions the individual values for the parameters might be of more importance, so using a meaningless function name like `foo` when asking for how to deal with the meaning of parameters is probably not the best idea.

Comment: Sensible solution.

Answer (score 6):

Why do we want to use named Constants instead of numbers?

1. DRY - If I need the value at 3 places, I only want to define it once, so I can change it at one place, if it changes.
2. Give meaning to numbers.

If you write several unit tests, each with an assortment of 3 Numbers (startBalance, interest, years ) - I would just pack the values into the unit-test as local variables. The smallest scope where they belong.

```
testBigInterest()
  var startBalance = 10;
  var interestInPercent = 100
  var years = 2
  assert( calcCreditSum( startBalance, interestInPercent, years ) == 40 )

testSmallInterest()
  var startBalance = 50;
  var interestInPercent = .5
  var years = 1
  assert( calcCreditSum( startBalance, interestInPercent, years ) == 50.25 )
```

If you use a language which allows named parameters, this is of course superflous. There I would just pack the raw values in the method call. I can't imagine any refactoring making this statement more concise:

```
testBigInterest()
  assert( calcCreditSum( startBalance:       10
                        ,interestInPercent: 100
                        ,years:               2 ) = 40 )
```

Or use a testing-Framework, which will allow you to define the test cases in some array or Map format:

```
testcases = { {
                Name: "BigInterest"
               ,StartBalance:       10
               ,InterestInPercent: 100
               ,Years:               2
              }
             ,{ 
                Name: "SmallInterest"
               ,StartBalance:       50
               ,InterestInPercent:  .5
               ,Years:               1
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

> ...but in this case the numbers actually have no meaning at all

The numbers are being used to call a method so surely the above premise is incorrect. You may not *care* what the numbers are but that is beside the point. Yes, you could infer what the numbers are used for by some IDE wizardry but it would be far better if you just gave the values names - even if they just match the parameters.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true, though -- as in the example of the most recent unit test I wrote (`assertEqual "Returned value" (makeKindInt 42) (runTest "lvalue_operators")`).  In this example, `42` is just a placeholder value that is produced by the code in the test script named `lvalue_operators` and then checked when it is returned by the script.  It has no meaning at all, other than that the same value occurs in two different places.  What would be an appropriate name here that actual gives any useful meaning?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) on one set of inputs that aren't boundary conditions, then you almost certainly want to test it on a *whole bunch* of sets of inputs that aren't (and are) boundary conditions.  And to me that means there should be a *table* of values to call the function with, and a loop:

```c
struct test_foo_values {
    int bar;
    int baz;
    int blurf;
    int expected;
};
const struct test_foo_values test_foo_with[] = {
   { 1, 2, 3, 17 },
   { 2, 4, 9, 34 },
   // ... many more here ...
};

for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(test_foo_with); i++) {
    const struct test_foo_values *c = test_foo_with[i];
    assertEqual(foo(c->bar, c->baz, c->blurf), c->expected);
}
```

Tools like those suggested in [Dannnno's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/322728/16303) can help you construct the table of values to test.  `bar`, `baz`, and `blurf` should be replaced by meaningful names as discussed in [Philipp's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/322717/16303).

(Arguable general principle here: Numbers are not always "magic numbers" that need names; instead, numbers might be **data**.  If it would make sense to put your numbers into an array, perhaps an array of records, then they're probably data.  Conversely, if you suspect you might have data on your hands, consider putting it into an array and acquiring more of it.)

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly let’s agree that “unit test” is often used to cover all automated tests a programmer writes, and that it is pointless to debate what each test should be called….*

I have worked on a system where the software took a lot of inputs and worked out a “solution” that had to fulfil some constraints, while optimizing other numbers.   **There were no right answers, so the software just had to give a reasonable answer.**

It did this by using lots of random numbers to get a starting point, then using a “hill climber” to improve the result.    This was run many times, picking the best result.  A random number generator can be seeded, so that it always gives the  same numbers out in the same order, hence if the test set a seed, we know that the result would be the same on each run.

We had lots of tests that did the above, and checked that the results were the same, this told us that we **had not changed** what that part of the system did by mistake while refactoring etc.   It did not tell us anything about the correctness of what that part of the system did.

These tests were costly to maintain, as any change to the optimising code would break the tests, but they also found some bugs in the much larger code that pre-processed the data, and post-processed the results.

As we “mocked” the database, you could call these tests “unit tests”, but the “unit” was rather large.

Often when you are working on a system with no tests, you do something like the above, so that you can confirm your refactoring don’t change the output; hopefully better tests are written for new code!

Answer (score 1):

Tests are different from production code and, at least in units tests written in Spock, which are short and to the point, I have no issue using magic constants.

If a test is 5 lines long, and follows the basic given/when/then scheme, extracting such values into constants would only make code longer and harder to read. If the logic is "When I add a user named Smith, I see the user Smith returned in user list", there is no point in extracting "Smith" to a constant.

This of course applies if you can easily match values used in the "given" (setup) block to those found in "when" and "then" blocks. If your test setup is separated (in code) from the place the data is used, it might indded be better to use constants. But since tests are best self-contained, setup is usually close to place of use and the first case applies, meaning magic constants are quite acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case the numbers should be termed Arbitrary Numbers, rather than Magic Numbers, and just comment the line as "arbitrary test case".

Sure, some Magic Numbers can be arbitrary too, as for unique "handle" values (which should be replaced with named constants, of course), but can also be precalculated constants like "airspeed of an unladen European sparrow in furlongs per fortnight", where the numeric value is plugged in without comments or helpful context.

Answer (score 0):

I won't venture as far as to say a definitive yes/no, but here are some questions you should ask yourself when deciding whether it's OK or not.

1. If the numbers don't mean anything, why are they there in the first place? Can they be replaced by something else? Can you do verification based on method calls and flow instead of value assertions? Consider something like Mockito's `verify()` method that checks whether or not certain method calls were made to mock objects instead of actually asserting a value.
2. If the numbers *do* mean something, then they should be assigned to variables that are named appropriately.
3. Writing the number `2`as `TWO` might be helpful in certain contexts, and not so much in other contexts.

   - For instance: `assertEquals(TWO, half_of(FOUR))`makes sense to someone who reads the code. It is immediately clear *what* you are testing.
   - If however your test is `assertEquals(numCustomersInBank(BANK_1), TWO)`, then this doesn't make *that* much sense. *Why* does `BANK_1` contain two customers? *What* are we testing for?